# Listener to be notified after view refreshes

Tags: android, android-layout

My project consists of a single Activity so far that loads a GridView that is populated by an extended BaseAdapter.
Typically the view is refreshed by calling BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from one of my OnClickListener objects.

My problem is that I need to start a timer each time the view is refreshed. I only want to do this when the view has been completely reloaded.

I can't seem to find a listener or method that I can override in either the View or Adapter APIs to perform this, although I presume there is one.
The closest I've found is BaseAdapter.registerDataSetObserver although I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for either.

Can anyone advise please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSetObserver won't provide the feature you're looking for. In your adapter try looking at [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) or ViewBinder.setViewBinder() (for the `Simple...Adapter` classes) once the last view is filled with data you'll be able to know, roughly, when its done.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I understand the ViewBinder concept...where would I get a handle on a SimpleAdapter or where would it fit in in my classes I've outlined above?

Comment: Is it a custom BaseAdapter or API base adapter?

Comment: This is a BaseAdapter that I've extended

Comment: That probably means you do your binding in getView, just wait for the last view to be populated then start your timer.

Comment: OK, I'll try that, although seems like somewhat of a "hack". Thanks for the suggestiomn

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet would be to create an anon inner class from this class and add your timer logic in an extension of `GridView`:

```
class AdapterDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {

    }
}
```

(You can access this member variable as it is not priveate):

```
/**
 * Should be used by subclasses to listen to changes in the dataset
 */
AdapterDataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;
```

This is the method that you should override (inside gridview) (You may need to make some modifications as some of these member variables may be private - `mDataSetObserver` is not, however:

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if (null != mAdapter) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }

    resetList();
    mRecycler.clear();
    mAdapter = adapter;

    mOldSelectedPosition = INVALID_POSITION;
    mOldSelectedRowId = INVALID_ROW_ID;

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mOldItemCount = mItemCount;
        mItemCount = mAdapter.getCount();
        mDataChanged = true;
        checkFocus();

        mDataSetObserver = new AdapterDataSetObserver();
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);

        mRecycler.setViewTypeCount(mAdapter.getViewTypeCount());

        int position;
        if (mStackFromBottom) {
            position = lookForSelectablePosition(mItemCount - 1, false);
        } else {
            position = lookForSelectablePosition(0, true);
        }
        setSelectedPositionInt(position);
        setNextSelectedPositionInt(position);
        checkSelectionChanged();
    } else {
        checkFocus();
        // Nothing selected
        checkSelectionChanged();
    }

    requestLayout();
}
```

Look for these two lines in the method above and extend your class here:

```
        mDataSetObserver = new AdapterDataSetObserver();
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not sure I understand the need to override setAdapter....why do I need to do this?